# G-local systems via the classifying stack BG

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, stacks, principal-bundles, classifying-spaces

First, let $BG$ be the classifying stack of a Lie group $G$ in either Top or Diff (compactly generated topological spaces or differentiable manifolds). A map $f: X \to BG$ determines a principal $G$-bundle $P \to X$ by base change of $* \to BG$.

Q: What conditions on $f$ allow us to conclude that $P$ is a $G$-local system?

I'll summarize my understanding of this below:

1. I've been able to find some discussion of this in terms of the Betti shape of $X$, denoted $X_B$, which is the stackification of the constant presheaf associated to $X$. A map of stacks $X_B \to BG$ determines a $G$-local system as it truncates to $\Pi_1(X) \to BG$ (see [Harrison Chen’s lecture notes](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Echenhi/notes/localsystems.pdf) or $\S$3 of [Mauro Porta and Francesco Sala notes](https://people.dm.unipi.it/sala/assets/pdf/porta_sala_shapes.pdf) for an analogous statement in the derived setting). So naively, I expect the condition on $f$ to imply it factors $X \to X_B \to BG$, where $X \to X_B$ is a natural 'sheafification' map.
2. Now, let $X$ be a CW complex and $\mathfrak{B}G$ be the classifying space. Because of the adjointness of the functors $\pi_1(-)$ and $\mathfrak{B}(-)$ (between pointed connected CW complexes and groups) we have a bijection between free homotopy classes of maps and conjugacy classes of representations
   $$ [X,\mathfrak{B}G] \to \hom(\pi_1(X),G)/G$$
   when we regard $G$ as a discrete group. So, I'd like to say $X \to \mathfrak{B}G$ is a $G$-local system when it factors $X \to \mathfrak{B}G_{disc} \to \mathfrak{B}G$ where $G_{disc}$ is $G$ with the discrete topology. This also appears to agree with the fact that $P \to X$ should come from a representation of $\pi_1(X)$ when its structure group is (can be reduced to) a finite group.

Comment: There are several questions asked here, and they are somewhat vague.  For instance, what is G?  A Lie group, a topological group, or, perhaps, a Lie ∞-group?  One possible definition of a local system on X is that it is a map X→LConst(S), where S is an ∞-groupoid, e.g., S=BG for an ∞-group G.  In this case, G can be a group, more generally, an ∞-group.  A Lie group G will not give a local system unless X→BG factors through LConst((BG)(pt))→BG, i.e., a local system with coefficients in the underlying discrete group of G.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Thank you for the comment (and sorry about being vague). I'll edit my post for clarity. For my purposes, I'd like G to be a Lie group but I would welcome an explanation in terms of ∞-groups. If you would be willing to briefly explain a link between factorization LConst((BG)(pt))→BG and the cases 1 & 2 mentioned in the post I will happily accept this as an answer.

Comment: This is really extra data on the map $f$, not a condition in general. E.g. in the category of smooth manifolds, say, this is the data of a flat connection on the corresponding bundle.